# Strip python string

Tags: python, string, strip, sysinternals

EDITED TO INCLUDE WORKING SCRIPT

Here is working script based on user's answers

```
import sys, subprocess, socket, string
import wmi, win32api, win32con



pst = subprocess.Popen(
        ["D:\pstools\psloggedon.exe", "-l", "-x", "\\\\10.10.10.10"],
        stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr = subprocess.PIPE
    )

out, error = pst.communicate()

userLoggedOn = out.split('\n')[1].strip()


print userLoggedOn, "is output"
```

---

---

---

---

I am trying to format output from a subprocess

Python script

```
import sys, subprocess, socket, string
import wmi, win32api, win32con



pst = subprocess.Popen(
        ["D:\pstools\psloggedon.exe", "-l", "-x", "\\\\10.10.10.10"],
        stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr = subprocess.PIPE
    )

out, error = pst.communicate()

userLoggedOn = out.strip('Users logged on locally:')


print userLoggedOn, "is output"
```

Gives the following output

```
Users logged on locally:
        DOMAIN\user
is output
```

How do I strip out "Users logged on locally:" so that it outputs

```
DOMAIN\user is output
```

Comment: `str.strip()` works on a **set**.

Comment: @MartijnPieters what? since when? Im confused now...(I couldnt make that work in python2.6 , and it doesnt make much since that it would since __set__ is inherently unordered ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley: since forever? `'Hello world!'.strip('Hel!')`.

Comment: @JoranBeasley: I meant that the characters in the argument are treated as a set, not a sequence.

Comment: ahhh ok that makes a little more sense then ... I thought you meant a `set("Hello")`

Comment: just do `out[len('Users logged on locally:'):]` or `re.sub("'Users logged on locally:',"",out)`,or `out.split(":",1)[-1]`

Comment: Using `out.split('\n')[1].strip()` should work also.

Comment: @GMGray --- your solution worked. How do I mark this thread as "solved" because of your answer?

Comment: @Glowie Write your own answer with what you've already tried for users looking answer for this question in the future ;)